# Dependices doesn't fit (java 8) installing JOSM on Linux

Tags: java, linux-mint, openjdk

I wanted to install JOSM on old Mint (https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Download#Ubuntu). So I added file josm.list to sources.list.d containing one line:

```
deb https://josm.openstreetmap.de/apt trusty universe
```

and tried:

```
# apt-get install josm
```

Translated output:

```
The following packages have unfulfilled dependencies:
 josm: Requires: openjdk-8-jre but can not be installed or
                 java8-runtime but can not be installed
```

but:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
```

I know it isn't latest 1.8.0_17x, but it is 1.8... What should I do to install josm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I posted question and minutes after I found a solution... So frequent...

```
# apt-add-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
# apt-get-update
# apt-get install josm
```

And JOSM is fully working, downloading data from OSM server.

Thanks for beeing rubber ducks! (truly, thank you)

Answer (score -1):

On
[JOSM download](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Download) webpage is descripbed how to add JOSM into your favourite distro.
Probably latest stable. In latest Mint 20.1 was josm outdated.
Link [1](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Download) helped me.